# Normal Map Weirdness...turns edges into crevices

Tags: normals, texture-baking, normal-map

I have weirdness happening baking normal maps from sculpted meshes in Cycles. It's treating some outward facing edges as crevices for some reason.

Attached pic shows a banged up spike. I duplicated the model and Remeshed it to get a good sculpting base. From there I baked the normals in the usual way. You can see all the hard corners of the spike are depressions or crevices now.

Any idea why? I recalculated the normals, and this seems to happen where hard edges were on the low-poly model. I don't understand where the problem could be happening.

[image]

Comment: Do you have displacement modifier or using Cycles true displacement?

Comment: I used the Displacement Modifier, fussed with the Ray Distance, even tried a cage, to no avail. Weird as it seems, I think it was because the target low-polly had (applied) beveled edges. I rebuilt the low poly and shrink-wraped it to the sculpt and that fixed the problem. Would still like to understand why this is happening.

Comment: I have this problem with displacement and when the edges are sharp. Not sure what the solution is other than turning all adjacent faces to smooth shading or somehow change your displacement to flatten near the edge (UV?)